# checking java is enabled or not in IE8 browser through

Tags: java, internet-explorer-8

Need help in finding whether java is enabled in IE8,

I Have used navigator.javaEnabled() which is always giving true even after disabling java in both places like,

1. Tools -> Internet Options -> Security -> Custom Level ->Scripting of
   Java Applets.
2. Tools -> Internet Options -> Advacnced -> Java (Oracle) -> JRE 1.7.0_17...

Can you please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

For IE8, navigator.javaEnabled() won't tell you whether Java is installed or not. It merely tells you if the applet tag is enabled or disabled.

The only way to reliably find out if java is installed (and enabled) is to try and run an applet. So make a test page, could even be in a hidden iFrame or something.

The page needs some JS, something like:

```
try {
    var x = document.getElementById('appletId').isRunning()
    return x;
} catch(e) {
    return false;
}
```

and down in the Body, add the applet tag:

```
<applet src=".../yourapplet.jar" id="appletId">
```

Of course, your applet should implement the method isRunning (or whatever you want to call it).  If you get True, java's there and running, otherwise you will get an exception which will be caught and return False.